OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to graph.facebook.com:443
I'm encountering an issue while implementing login with Facebook APIs in my Laravel(v5.7) application. When attempting to connect to the Facebook Graph API endpoint (graph.facebook.com:443), I'm receiving the following error:
OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to graph.facebook.com:443
This error occurs during the authentication process, and it's preventing users from logging in using their Facebook accounts
code snippet:
public function addFacebookAccount($adsAccount = false)     {         $message = "Your account is connected. Check back later as data is populated.";         $helper = $this->connection()->getRedirectLoginHelper();         if ($state = \Request::get('state', null)) {             $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $state);         }         try {             $token = (string) $helper->getAccessToken();             if ($adsAccount) {                 $fb_user = (new Support\Endpoints\FacebookUser($token))->me();                 $account = FacebookApi::firstOrCreate([                     'company_id'        => \App\Models\Client::current(),                     'social_account_id' => $fb_user['id']                 ], ['social_account_name' => $fb_user['name']]);                                  $account->access_token = $token;                 $account->save();                 $this->initializeAdAccountTokens($account->social_account_id, $account->access_token, $account->company_id);             } else {                 $fb_user = (new Support\Endpoints\FacebookUser($token))->me();                 $account = FacebookApi::firstOrCreate([                     'company_id'        => \App\Models\Client::current(),                     'social_account_id' => $fb_user['id']                 ], ['social_account_name' => $fb_user['name'], 'is_disabled' => 0]);                                  $account->access_token = $token;                 $account->save();                 $this->insertUserPageTokens($account);             }         } catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {             // When Graph returns an error             \Log::info('Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());             $message = 'We could not log you in at this time';         } catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {             // When validation fails or other local issues             \Log::info('Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());             $message = 'We could not log you in at this time';         } return isset($fb_user) ? ['info' => $message, 'name' => $fb_user['name']]:          ['info' => $message];     }

my logs file :
Facebook SDK returned an error: OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to graph.facebook.com:443enter image description here

How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?
